# how could i connect to Ambari from hortonworks through url "sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080"?

Tags: virtualbox, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

i got installed Hortonworks data platform (HDP 2.4) on oracle virtual box, when i trying to use storm streaming analytics it uses to connect ambari by url

> sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080

instead of

> 127.0.0.1:8080

loop back address and i got an error message over browser

> Error : This site can’t be reached

so tell me that how could i assign

> sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080

domain name to loop back address from virtual machine OS terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

to-

If you're on a windows machine, this file

```
%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

If you're on a Mac, then, this file

```
/etc/hosts
```

This will need to be done for your host machine(the one on which you installed VirtualBox) and not inside the VM.

If you are using bridged mode or host-only-adapter, replace the `127.0.0.1` with your VM's IP, so it should look like

```
192.168.56.101 localhost sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

That should help you use the FQDN.